# blackberry webworks upload with parameters

Tags: blackberry, parameters, upload, blackberry-webworks

Is there any way to upload a file sending additional parameter (like AJAX or so) with Blackberry WebWorks? (I tried to use Phonegap FileTransfer, but it doesn't work for me at all. Secondly, I tried WebWorks UploadDownload extension, it works fine, but there is no possibility to send parameters.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using XHR2?

Good article over here - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/

Answer (score 0):

As I heard, XHR isn't working on Blackberry Playbook